# How can I get proj4text from srtext?

Tags: postgis, srid

I have a custom projection used in some shapes on a prj file. 
I want to insert this projection in the table spatial_ref_sys PostGIS. 
The data in the prj file will SRTEXT table field, how can I get PROJ4TEXT from SRTEXT??

```
INSERT into spatial_ref_sys
 (srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text, srtext)
values 
( 101010, 'epsg', 101010, '?????????????', 
'GEOGCS["Carta Geral",DATUM["Not specified (based on International 1924 ellipsoid) (EPSG ID",SPHEROID["International 1924 (EPSG ID 7022)",6378388.0,297.0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",200000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",5000000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-51.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just copy the string into a text file named `crs.txt`, and run `gdalsrsinfo crs.txt >> out.txt` in the OSGeo4W Shell or Linux Terminal on it:

```
PROJ.4 : '+proj=longlat +ellps=intl +no_defs '

OGC WKT :
GEOGCS["Carta Geral",
    DATUM["Not specified (based on International 1924 ellipsoid) (EPSG ID",
        SPHEROID["International 1924 (EPSG ID 7022)",6378388.0,297.0]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful